# I tried to upgrade Geth to 1.4.6, now I get fatal error "Error starting protocol stack datadir already used"

Tags: go-ethereum

I tried to upgrade Geth to 1.4.6, now I get this error, why and how can I fix it?

Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used

OS: Ubuntu 15.10

Note: Chaindata is being symlinked to an external SD card, not sure if that is relevant

Answer (score 3):

Seems you already have a Geth instance running in the background that has the database locked.

Answer (score 2):

Check for running geth instaces using `ps`.

```
 ~ $ ps aux | grep geth
user     10382  6.2  0.4 643660 66508 pts/0    Sl+  10:17   0:00 geth
user     10408  0.0  0.0  13164  2288 pts/1    S+   10:17   0:00 grep --color=auto geth
```

Kill it softly.

```
 ~ $ killall geth
```

If the issue persists, and geth is not wanting to be killed softly, look up the process ID from `ps` (above, here: 10382), and kill it hard:

```
 ~ $ kill -9 10382
```

Now you can launch geth again. However, you could also just `geth attach` to check if geth is running.